How to interpret IBC 1010.1.7?
1010.1.7 Thresholds states...

Thresholds at doorways shall not exceed 3/4 inch (19.1 mm) in height above the finished floor or landing for sliding doors serving dwelling units or 1/2 inch (12.7 mm) above the finished floor or landing for other doors. Raised thresholds and floor level changes greater than 1/4 inch (6.4 mm) at doorways shall be beveled with a slope not greater than one unit vertical in two units horizontal (50-percent slope).

Emphasis mine...does this mean that floor level changes under interior doors are permitted to exist at a 50% slope?! That would mean that a standard 4 9/16 doorway could drop over 2 inches between finished floor planes.
That seems like a trip hazard to me.  Is this section poorly worded, or am I misinterpreting the code here?

I believe that is why a slope is required.  So your foot/toe slides over instead of a sudden stop(a trip) with a two inch straight drop.

I'm questioning this primarily because if we look at similar requirements for ramps and such, a 50% grade is much steeper than permissible.  I don't have any specific citation, but I recall seeing ramps needing at least 12 horizontal units per one vertical unit.

My gut feeling (but no real experience with this code, so not an answer) is that while there is no set maximum here, the expectation is that this will be at most a couple of inches so it is effectively "a bump up or down" much more than it would be "a ramp". A ramp has to have a low slope for safety not just when walking but also wheelchairs (and walkers, strollers, etc.) can make it safely up/down. With a "transition" it is effectively like a bump in the road and requiring a slope makes it require a good push to get over it rather than having to lift as would be the case with an actual step.

Also consider that while 2" is probably a bit excessive, it isn't that unusual to have 1" of transition height - e.g., from a bare concrete floor on one side to subfloor + padding + carpet (or other built up floor) on the other side. In which case a 1-in-12 slope would require a 12" transition which would really eat into floor space in one room or the other. But 1-in-2 means a 2" transition, which is no big deal.
